# ROracle installation: Unable to load shared object error

Tags: r, oracle, installation, roracle

- I need to connect R to an Oracle database
- Followed the instructions on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ROracle/INSTALL, exactly, step by step
- Getting the following error:

```
library('ROracle')
Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) :
    unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/Daniel/R/winlibrary/3.2/ROracle/libs/x64/ROracle.dll':
    LoadLibrary failure:  %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

[image]

---

I don't know where to start fixing this. Here's the results of `libPath()`:

````
> .libPaths()
"C:/Users/Daniel/R/win-library/3.2"  "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.3```
````

library('ROracle')
/library"

---

Windows 10, R version 3.2.3

Comment: Does `C:/Users/Daniel/R/winlibrary/3.2/ROracle/libs/x64/ROracle.dll` exist?

Comment: It does. ROracle.dll is the only file in that directory.
I checked the path and it's correct.

Comment: Having only done this installation once or twice on Windows, all I can suggest is that I recall having to be careful about installing and running either all 32-bit or all 64-bit versions of all pieces, from the Oracle InstantClient, down to R. Just based on your error messages, it seems possible you could be mixing/matching those flavors.

Comment: Thanks @joran. I believe I've triple-checked all components to make sure they're all 64-bit but in case I don't get any solutions here I'll make sure to start from zero with that in min.

Comment: @Dan did you manage to solve the problem? If so, could you share your solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These two steps should fix it for you:

1. Rename your "Path" environmental variable to "PATH"
2. Install the ROracle package only after you have set the Oracle Instant Client in environmental variables. (Just run install.packages() again)

Answer (score 0):

try to run RStudio with administration privilege, I solved this problem with it.