# ROracle Installation-Unable to load shared objects ROracle.dll

Tags: r, roracle, rtools

I am trying to install the ROracle package on my Windows 10 64-bit system. R version is Microsoft R Open 3.5.0.

I changed the "Path" name in environment variable to "PATH" as suggested by the right answer to this question [ROracle installation :: Unable to load shared object error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36802847/roracle-installation-unable-to-load-shared-object-error). I am still unable to get a solution to this problem.
 Below is the package installation run and it's result.

```
> install.packages("ROracle")


* installing *source* package 'ROracle' ...
** package 'ROracle' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
/cygdrive/c/oracleclient/instantclient_18_3/genezi.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
/cygdrive/c/oracleclient/instantclient_18_3/genezi.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
[: 64-bit: unknown operand
[: 32-bit: unknown operand
Oracle
found Oracle Client C:\oracleclient\instantclient_18_3
found Oracle Client include C:\oracleclient\instantclient_18_3\sdk\include
copying from C:\oracleclient\instantclient_18_3\sdk\include
** libs
Warning: this package has a non-empty 'configure.win' file,
so building only the main architecture

c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~2/ROPEN~1/R-35~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -I./oci    -I"C:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.5.0/vendor/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c rodbi.c -o rodbi.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -m64 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~2/ROPEN~1/R-35~1.0/include" -DNDEBUG -I./oci    -I"C:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.5.0/vendor/extsoft/include"     -O2 -Wall  -std=gnu99 -mtune=core2 -c rooci.c -o rooci.o
c:/Rtools/mingw_64/bin/gcc -m64 -shared -s -static-libgcc -o ROracle.dll tmp.def rodbi.o rooci.o C:\oracleclient\instantclient_18_3/oci.dll -LC:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.5.0/vendor/extsoft/lib/x64 -LC:/swarm/workspace/External-R-3.5.0/vendor/extsoft/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/MICROS~2/ROPEN~1/R-35~1.0/bin/x64 -lR
installing to C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/ROracle/libs/x64
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'ROracle' in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/xxxx/Documents/R/win-library/3.5/ROracle/libs/x64/ROracle.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing 'C:/Users/xxxx /Documents/R/win-library/3.5/ROracle'
In R CMD INSTALL
Warning in install.packages :
installation of package ‘ROracle’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I've been struggling with this error message as well; tried several different InstantClient versions back to 12_1, several older versions of ROracle, no luck so far. I'm using the normally distributed R 3.5.2, tho, not the Microsoft one.